# ThreeJs Texture doesnt load after building a project

Tags: javascript, three.js

Ok, so I decided to learn three js and was following Gary Simon's tutorial "Getting Started with THREE.JS in 2021!". Everything works fine on localhost, however when you build the project the sphere doesn't load the textures. There are no console errors or warnings, and the network tab shows no requests being made to load the texture. Here are the images of what it looks like on local vs build. Any ideas why textures would load on the local but not the final product. Seems like it doesn't like this lines of code

```
const normalTexture = textureLoader.load('/textures/NormalMap.png');
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial();
material.metalness=0.7;
material.roughness=0.2;
material.normalMap = normalTexture;
material.color = new THREE.Color(0x292929);

// Mesh
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material)
scene.add(sphere)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you share your code structure?

Comment: https://ibb.co/1LB8HwH